# Qt QListView with different delegates per column

Tags: qt, delegates

The Delegate system is not clear to me by now.

I have a QListView properly displaying my custom model.

My model is composed by the following columns:

- Column 1, 2 and 3 are a Text column, the column's item's text is filled using `QAbstractItem::setText();`
- Column 4, 5, 6 and 7 are a QVariant of a custom class. These column have items filled with `QAbstractItem::setData(QVariant::fromValue(MyCustomClass());`

What I need from the QListView is it to display the text on the column 1,2 and 3, and display a custom QString obtained by a method of MyCustomClass on clumns 4,5,6 and 7.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `QAbstractItemView::setItemDelegateForColumn(int column, QAbstractItemDelegate* delegate)`, [docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#setItemDelegateForColumn).

Have you got a custom model?  If all you are pulling out of your custom data is text, it would be easier to reimplement `QAbstractItemModel::data(const QModelIndex& index, int role) const`, query which column `index` is, and if it is your custom data column return the display role with the custom data text; otherwise just call the parent implementation.

Comment: Great idea to reimplement data method. Thanks!!